# Why jenkins terminate batch step execution on windows

Tags: jenkins

I am running jenkins job on windows10. And during the job execution, it will keep creating and killing processes. It seems that jenkins terminate the job execution when there is a process get killed. I have set the environment variable `BUILD_ID=dontKillMe` on jenkins project. Why does it terminate the job execution?
I get below log on jenkins console output:

```
10:39:38 ^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? ^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? 
10:39:38 ^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

Detail about the job execution:

This job is used to build nodejs electron project and run test cases by spectron. During the test case running, some mongod database processes are created and after finish running the tests, mongod process will be killed. Different test suite requires different mongod process, some of them uses single instance while some uses replica or shard cluster. So the mongod process is launched in `beforeAll` method and killed in `afterAll` for each test suite. I found that when I killed a mongod instance in afterAll, the job will be terminated. It works fine on local run but not work through jenkins. The command used to trigger the test cases is `yarn test`

Comment: What is your job supposed to do? Do you have the config.xml of the job that you can post?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have posted the detail about this job execution and where I can find config.xml for this job?

Comment: I've recently started seeing a similar behavior in sub-jobs of a matrix build running on Windows Server and Linux (Ubuntu) executors. I haven't gotten to the cause yet.
Here is an issue that seems similar, but no followup was taken.
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31190